# Nine Red Rose Flowers

Tags: riddle

There are nine perfect red rose flowers that have all a unique number of petals. One rose in the bouquet is dead and one rose has only one petal. How are there nine perfect red rose flowers when two are not perfect?

Answer (score 3):

This is because

> There are 11 flowers in the bouquet.

So,

> 9 good flowers + 2 bad flowers = 11